# How to open Windev HFSQL Fic files

Tags: database, windev, hyperfilesql

I'm trying to read a FIC file that is not encrypted (indeed, the data can almost be read when displaying it). I want to convert this file to a more convenient format, CSV, XML, SQL, etc...

When I try to open it with Windev Express 19, I have an error telling me that the file is password protected. But If there really was a password, the file would be encrypted (I think).

If someone has any idea about what could be the problem. Or any suggestion, I'd be glad.

Comment: What do you mean by "the data can almost be read when displaying it" ? You should be able to open it by double-clicking it, it should open with WDMAP and you will be able to export the datas to Excel with a right click.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FIC extension is not only used by Windev but also by Pervasive SQL. One should also check if it can be opened using Pervasive clients.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to the party but i've been able to open several `.fic` `.ndx` `.mmo` and `.ftx` files with this software called HFDA (HyperFileSQL Data Access) : https://www.lapalys.ca/logiciels/hfda/

Note that the free version has limited features, and an account creation is required in order to download it. But at least one can view/edit or export tables in various formats such as `csv` or `xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Encryption and password protection are two different features in WINDEV.
You really need the file password to open it (even if the content is not encrypted).

Comment: Actually, I discovered that FIC files are not only used by Windev. This extension is also used by Pervasive SQL. I was just using the wrong software to open the files.